# Count words, java

Tags: java, char, switch-statement

I want to count words. I use the methods **hasNextChar** and **getChar**. The sentence may contain all kind of chars. Here's my code:

```
        boolean isWord = false;

        while(hasNextChar()){
            char current = getChar();   
            switch(current){
                case ' ' : case '.' : case ',' : case '-' :
                    isWord = false;
                default:
                    if(!isWord) wordCount++;
                    isWord = true;
            }
        }
```

It works so far but e.g. when I have a " . " at the end it gives me 8 instead of 7 words. Here are some examples of sentences:

*„Schreiben Sie ein Praktikanten-Vermittlungs-Programm“ – words: 6

„Du magst ja recht haben – aber ich sehe das ganz anders.“ – words: 11

„Hallo Welt !!!!“ – words: 2

„Zwei Wörter !!!!“ – words: 2

„Eins,Zwei oder Drei“ – words: 4*

A sentence does not have to end with a " . ".

Any ideas how to solve that?

Comment: Are you trying to count characters (word characters in this case)? Or actual words?

Comment: I want to count words but the caracters of the the sentence are given, it is not allowed to use arrays...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You forgot the [`break` statement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switch_statement#C.2C_C.2B.2B.2C_Java.2C_php.2C_ActionScript.2C_Javascript) in the first `case` (after `isWord = false`).

Answer (score 3):

Since it's homework I won't solve it for you but point you in the right direction instead.

Take a look at the `Character` class and the helper methods it defines. (Hint: they are all called *`isXyz()`*)

**Reference:**

- Sun Apidocs: [Character](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html)
- Sun Java Tutorial: [Characters](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html)

---

For the heck of it: here's a oneliner method to count the words using Regex. Don't use this solution, come up with your own. This is probably not what your teachers want to see, anyway.

**Method:**

```
public static int countwords(final String phrase) {
    return phrase.replaceAll("[^\\p{Alpha}]+", " ").trim().split(" ").length;
}
```

**Test code:**

```
System.out.println(countwords(
        "Schreiben Sie ein Praktikanten-Vermittlungs-Programm"));
System.out.println(countwords(
        "Du magst ja recht haben – aber ich sehe das ganz anders."));
System.out.println(countwords("Hallo Welt !!!!"));
System.out.println(countwords("Zwei Wörter !!!!"));
System.out.println(countwords("Eins,Zwei oder Drei"));
```

**Output:**

> 6
>   11
>   2
>   3
>   4

**Explanation:**
To use a phrase coined by Henry Rollins: Let's milk it, shall we?

```
// replace any occurrences of non-alphabetic characters with a single space
// this pattern understands unicode, so e.g. German Umlauts count as alphabetic
phrase.replaceAll("[^\\p{Alpha}]+", " ")

// trim space off beginning and end
.trim()

// split the string, using the spaces as delimiter
.split(" ")

// the length of the resulting array is the number of words
.length;
```

Answer (score 2):

Going off of Michael McGowan comment,

The logic seems backwards to me.  Shouldn't the detection of a space or punctuation signify you found a word?

And is there any restraints on how your sentence is formed?  If you had a sentence with `"One,_Two,Three,Four,____Five"`, then the algorithm would need additional logic to handle consecutive spaces/punctuations.

Comment: @Woot4Moo, good catch.

Why not just ignore hyphens? I am assuming the hyphen is used for words and not new line returns that break up 1 word across two sentences.

Comment: they fall under the umbrella of punctuation and I think that technically that a hyphenated word counts as two distinct words.  I am not an English major though.

Comment: @Woot4Moo, nor am I an English major :).

Comment: I'm a linguistics and NLP major, and I can tell you that the definition of a word varies so widely that the OP'd better do as his teacher says :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the class StringTokenizer from java.util and this would get really easyer. As parameters for the contruction use the string you have and all the delimiters you want.

```
StringTokenizer s = new StringTokenizer(yourString, ",. :;/");
int cantWords = s.countTokens();
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's walk through a little example: "I am."

Iteration 1: current = 'I'; wordCount = 1; isWord = true;

Iteration 2: current = ' '; isWord = false; wordCount = 2; isWord = true;

Iteration 3: current = 'a'; isWord = true;

Iteration 4: current = 'm'; isWord = true;

Iteration 5: current = '.'; isWord = false; wordCount = 3; isWord = true;

Did you intentionally leave out the break in your switch?  The logic you used seems a bit strange to me.